# How make a transition between several ViewControllers from SKScene?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, viewcontroller, skscene

I'm looking for changing my ViewController from a gameScene with SpriteKit.
I have 3 scenes with 3 different ViewControllers.

When my application starts with the PresentationViewController (see the screenshot 1) my transition code from my GameScene (GameViewController) to the GameOverViewController doesn't work and I can read an error message.
[image: screenshot1]

error message :

```
whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

My code is :

```
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let settingController: UIViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PresentationViewController") as UIViewController
    let vc = self.view?.window?.rootViewController
    vc?.presentViewController(settingController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

And when my app starts with the GameViewController (see the screenshot 2) the transition code works perfectly.

[image: screenshot2]

I don't know why is there a difference between this 2 cases.

For information the transition between PresentationViewController and GameViewController is with a UIButton with this code :

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    var playButton   = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System) as UIButton
    let image = UIImage(named: "playButton.png") as UIImage

    playButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)
    playButton.center = CGPointMake(self.view.frame.width/2, self.view.frame.height/1.7)
    playButton.addTarget(self, action: "transition:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    playButton.setBackgroundImage(image, forState: UIControlState.Normal)

    self.view.addSubview(playButton)

}

func transition(sender:UIButton!)
{

    println("transition")
    let secondViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("GameViewController") as UIViewController

    secondViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.CrossDissolve
    self.presentViewController(secondViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I found by myself a way to navigate between several `ViewController`. 
I set the secondViewController to be the `rootViewController` in replace this code in my PresentationViewController file `func transition()`:

```
self.presentViewController(secondViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)`
```

by this code (with options) :

```
secondViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.CrossDissolve
let window = UIApplication.sharedApplication().windows[0] as UIWindow
UIView.transitionFromView(
    window.rootViewController!.view,
    toView: secondViewController.view,
    duration: 0.65,
    options: .TransitionCrossDissolve,
    completion: {
        finished in window.rootViewController = secondViewController
})
```